# add extra json data to django serialized json data

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I have jsonified the django model. e.g.

```
from django.core import serializers

foos = Foo.objects.all()

data1 = serializers.serialize('json', foos)
```

I want to add some extra json data to data1, e.g.

```
from django.utils import simplejson

some_data = {'some_var_1': 'foo'}

data2 = simplejson.dumps(data)
```

how can I combine data1 and data2.
Serializing foos and some_data gives "_meta" not found error.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve:
(after the line some_data = {'some_var_1': 'foo'})

```
data3 = simplejson.loads(data1)
data3.append(some_data)
simplejson.dumps(data3)
```